# Process crashed in debugger; how do I kill it

Tags: macos, gdb, cgdb

I've got a C++ application which connects over a USB serial link to a microprocessor, (similar to an Arduino). I use `termios.h` as my serial wrapper.

I'm debugging using `cgdb` on Mac OS X `10.7.3`.

When I:

- `cgdb build/my-process`
- Set some breakpoints, etc, do some debugging
- Find a bug, or try to exit the *still running process* using `kill` inside `cgdb`

the process hangs. `cgdb` refuses to ever kill the process - just sits there. I'm *fairly* sure this is because if I `kill` from halfway through the application, I never release the `/dev/ttyUSB` device that I'm accessing the microcontroller through. I'm not sure if something gets locked and never unlocked, but `cgdb` never exits.

I've tried:

- Basic interrupts: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- `ps aux | grep 'my-process',`kill -9 [pid]`.
- `ps aux | grep cgdb`, `kill -9 [pid]`.
- `sudo` versions of the above.

Nothing kills either `cgdb` or the process running in it.

If I remove the USB cable (terminate connection to microprocessor), (I thought that might crash the crashed process), I start seeing ~50% available CPU being used (not sure on what), and everything locks up. I **don't** manage to crash the application.

How do you: **(a)** exit cleanly *without* locking everything up from `cgdb` or `gdb` while in the middle of debugging a process, **or (b)** kill / cleanly (although 'cleanly' would just be icing on the cake) stop a process that's stopped while you're debugging it that *isn't* responding to `kill -9` **without** rebooting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't kill a process that's in an I/O wait. That's been true for most if not all Unix kernels from the dawn of the epoch.

It sounds like a debugger (or any process that's `ptrace`ing another) that's stuck in an I/O wait can't be killed, either.

Comment: Nope, it's essentially an uninterruptible state. The only way to get out the state is to cause the kernel I/O operation to complete, successfully or not.

Comment: That's a slight pain - thanks. I've been bashing my head trying to figure out how to kill the silly thing for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

ptrace or pgrep

I would try "pgrep -l cgdb" very handy for listing the pid...